# Get Full Date Only in Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I have strings that includes the dates. I wanted to get the `full date` only.
If there's no year, just add the current year of 4 digits.

**Sample**

```
Nov 29 2019
abc 0 May 30 2020
ddd Apr 3 2021 efg
0 Jan 3 hellodewdde deded
```

[https://regex101.com/r/pLUQNe/1](http://REGEX%20LINK)

**Regex**

```
(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) \d{1,2}?)
```

Comment: In the second line `abc 0 May 30 2020`, why does the first `0` need to match? Which date do you expect it to be? To me it is 30-May-2020, so first `0` should not be relevant...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the following regex pattern:

```regex
(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) \d{1,2}(?: \d{4})?
```

```js
var dates = ["Nov 29 2019", "abc 0 May 30 2020", "ddd Apr 3 2021 efg", "0 Jan 3 hellodewdde deded", "Green eggs and ham"];
var months = "(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)";
var regex = new RegExp(months + " \\d{1,2}(?: \\d{4})?");
var matches = [];

for (var i=0; i < dates.length; ++i) {
    var date = dates[i].match(regex);
    if (date != null) {
        if (date[0].match(/ \d{4}$/)) {
            matches.push(date[0]);
        }
        else {
            matches.push(date[0] + " " + new Date().getFullYear());
        }
    }
}

console.log(matches);
```

The logic here is that we detect if the matching date has a ending 4 digit year.  If not, then we append the current year to the month/day match.